# Database structure not updating

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, devise

So I'm trying to use `:lockable` in Devise, but I need to modify the table. So I added  the following code to devise.rb

```
t.integer  :failed_attempts, default: 0, null: false # Only if lock strategy is :failed_attempts
t.string   :unlock_token # Only if unlock strategy is :email or :both
t.datetime :locked_at
add_index :users, :unlock_token,         unique: true
```

And then migrated along with a server restart. Then I ran `User.new.attributes`, but the new additions still don't show. Any ideas?

Comment: If you are adding new columns to an existing database, it needs to be added in a new migration files - something like `rails generate migration AddLockableToUsers` - which will generate a new file in the db/migration directory - edit that new file to add your new columns then run `rake db:migrate` to apply the changes - see the guides for more info: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html

Comment: Do I copy only the new code, or all of the code plus my addition? @house9

Comment: Oh alright. And for the name `rails generate migration AddLockableToUsers` what if I wanted to do something else? @JamesMason

Answer (score 0):

When adding migration, start with the migration command `rails g migration` followed by `AddColumnnameToModelname`. don't ignore the capitalization. followed by `columnname:field_type`

so lets say you want to add `unlock_token` of type `string` to migration, this is what you'll do:

```
rails g migration AddUnlockTokenToUser unlock_token:string
```

you can also simply run `rails g migration AddUnlockTokenToUser` then manually add the column name along with the field type to the generated migration file.

then run `rake db:migrate`

your db schema should now be updated.